# $(n + a)^{b} = \Theta(n^{b})$ using limits?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

At university we were told that $(n + a)^{b} = \Theta(n^{b})$ can be proven by finding $c_1$, $c_2$ and $n_0$.

$a, b \in \mathbb{R} $ with $b > 0$

The professor said it is not possible to solve this by using limits. But I do not quite understand why this is the case. Could somebody please tell me why limits cannot be applied here?

Thanks.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Natural? Real?

Comment: Both are real, but b must be > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are saying by "using limits". Here is a proof using the definition of a limit:

As $\dfrac{(n+a)^b}{n^b} \longrightarrow_{n\to \infty} 1$, then there exists $n_0 \geqslant 1$ such that for every $n \geqslant n_0$ :
\begin{align}
1-\dfrac{1}{2} \leqslant \dfrac{(n+a)^b}{n^b} \leqslant 1+\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
(I applied the definition of the limit with $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$) Thus, thus, for all $n \geqslant n_0$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}n^b \leqslant (n+a)^b \leqslant \frac{3}{2}n^b
\end{align}
and $(n+a)^b = \Theta(n^b)$.

But you cannot say that if $u_n$ and $v_n$ both have the same limit at infinity, then $u_n=\Theta(v_n)$. A counter-example is $u_n = n$ and $v_n = n^2$. They both go to infinity but $u_n \neq \Theta(v_n)$.

Comment: Basically we learned that if the limit of f(n)/g(n) = K>0 (when n-> infinity), then f(n) = Theta(g(n)). However, this seems to not be possible to apply here. I added the definitions for a and b in the post. Could it be linked to the definition of a?

Comment: If $f(n)/g(n) \to K >0$, then the same proof I write with $\varepsilon = K/2$ show that $K/2f(n) \leqslant g(n) \leqslant 3/2Kf(n)$ and therefore, that $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$. It does not depend on the value of a because as $a$ is constant and has we are looking for asymptotic near $+\infty$, there is no big deal.